# Firebase security rules: allow 'get' when document has a specific field

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

My user signup process looks like

1. buy a license on Stripe
2. complete account afterwards

In the Stripe webhook/cloud function, we get information on the email and the license and we store this in a new document in the firestore `stripe-customers` collection (with a generated id).

When completing the account afterwards, we ask email/password, authenticate with firebase and we create a document in the firestore `customers` collection (with id=uid)

In order to check whether a user has a valid license I want to give an authenticated user  'read' access to the stripe-customer with the matching email address. So I want to somehow check that `customer/uid/email (or auth.token.email) == stripe-customer/id/email`

I tried the following security rules but apparently, for 'read', `request` does not have a `resource` property.

How can I test against the value of a property in a document?

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /customers/{uid} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth != null && request.auth.uid == uid;
    }
    match /stripe-customers/{id} {
      allow read: if request.resource.data.email == request.auth.token.email;
    }
  }
}
```

And some related questions:

- are there benefits in using `uid` as document-id versus having a generated id and a document uid property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `request.resource` variable contains the future state of the document when *updating/creating* a document. Instead use `resource.data` that is a map of all of the fields and values stored in the document.

```
match /stripe-customers/{id} {
  allow read: if resource.data.email == request.auth.token.email;
}
```

You can read more about this in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-conditions).

---

> Are there benefits in using uid as document-id versus having a generated id and a document uid property?

Depends on use case, here I would prefer user's auth UID as document ID in customers collection and customer ID from Stripe as doc ID in stripe-customers collection. There isn't any advantage, but it just easier to get user's document from Firestore `.doc('customers' + uid)` instead of using a `where('userId', '==', uid)` queries.

Comment: Using resource.data works indeed! Thank you for the pointer to the documentation and for sharing your insights!  It's appreciated!